# UIAlertView not called in NSObject class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created one `NSObject` class in which I created some common functions. I created function which show `UIAlertView`. It works fine. But when I click on alert button, `didDismissWithButtonIndex` delegate method not called.

```
+ (void)showMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:JMESSAGETITLE message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert postHideAlertNotification:0];
    [alert show];
}


#pragma mark - UIAlertView Delegate

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}
```

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: whats is the error you get

Comment: did you set delegate?

Comment: please set alert view delegate in your nsobject class then only delegate method will get call

Comment: try to use the delegate  clickedButtonAtIndex

Comment: Make sure the object still exists after the alert is shown.

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated; It would be good option to use UIAlertController.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **self** in this line

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:JMESSAGETITLE message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

indicates the **NSObject** class not an object. You have to change the class method to instance method or create an object of **NSObject** class and set this object as delegate.

For object creation you can use singleton pattern.

```
+ (YourClass *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static YourClass *sharedMyClass;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
        sharedMyClass = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyClass;
}

+ (void)showMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: JMESSAGETITLE message:message delegate:[YourClass sharedInstance] cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Comment: Not working... I created object of class. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Confirm to `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol in the NSObject class like this:

`@interface yourClass : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>`

Make `UIAlertView *alert` object as instance variable of the class or 
property. Like this:

```
@interface yourClass : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView *alert;
@end
```

In the method where you are using the `alert` object, set the delegate `self.alert.delegate = self`